# Forticlient SSL VPN on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: vpn

I have using Forticlient SSL VPN... I can connect... and I have a status message "Tunnel running" but I cant navigate any IP address of the VPN, for example 10.10.201.17 on google chrome... to see a web page in the remote network...
I ping that address, and I dont receive any message from that IP

Answer (score 1):

The route to the remote network should be pushed by the VPN server to which the SSLVPN connection is established.

Could you check if the routes to the remote network are added once the SSLVPN connection is established?

You can verify this by executing the following command in the terminal-

```
netstat -r
```